# SPSite can't find site

Tags: powershell, spsite

We recently began using a load balancer to force HTTPS on our SharePoint, and the PowerShell code below can no longer find the site. I've tried using both https://mysite and //mysite, with the same results.

```
    [void][System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
    $site    =     new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://mysite")
    $web     =    $site.rootweb
    $list    =    $web.Lists["mylist"]
```

Comment: Are you able to navigate to your site using your browser?

Comment: Yes. I also included the http address in Alternate Access Mappings in Central Admin.

Comment: Clarification - I can get to the site using the browser on my own computer. When I connect remotely to the server, and visit the site using the server's browser, it asks for credentials.

Comment: So what error you are getting? does the account that PS runs can log in to site?

Comment: The error message says the web application cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. We were able to fix the farm account's permissions by logging in with an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can ping this site proper, otherwise create record in HOST file, do ipconfig /flushdns and try access with Internet Browser on Server. You can also try `$wa = Get-SPWebApplication` and list all Sites Here `$wa.Sites` if its listed here.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and got the message "The local farm is not accessible."

Comment: So you havent set Permissions for running scripts, you need to have SPShellAdmin https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/add-spshelladmin?view=sharepoint-ps and be in part of Farm Administrator group

Comment: That produces the error "cannot access the local farm," which doesn't make sense since I'm using the farm account. I'm running PowerShell ISE as an admin.

Comment: Are you running script on proper SP server? Can you open Farm Administration?

Comment: Do you mean Central Admin? When the other admin accounts were removed, I lost the icons that were saved in the taskbar. I can get to Central Admin by going through IIS and loading "localhost" followed by the port number, but that's separate from the Central Admin for the site itself.

Comment: I dont understand now, you changed admin accounts? Make sure you are accessing correct Central Administration and that you have set proper permissions (Farm Administration Group on SharePoint) and in SQL Instance for SharePoint (You need set the ShellAdmin role in minimum.). Because you now have not proper permissions for doing what you want.

Comment: Correction - I was using the farm account before the changeover and now I'm using the system account. I don't know if the two have the same permissions.

Comment: so verify it, AD groups, Farm Administration Group, SQL Instance as i said, after this you will be able to run PS scripts. Mark answer please.

Comment: I switched to an account that is in the Farm Administrators Group, and I verified this through Central Admin. I ran the Get-SPDatabase | SPShellAdmin command and I get the same results. I tried starting the Management Shell instead of PowerShell and it says the local farm is not accessible. Could this be related to the new load balancer?

Comment: I dont know, i dont know your environment, but this is about accessing Config and Application databases, so make sure you have this permission on them.

Comment: Do you know how I can check the permissions on those if I can't run PS or Management Shell? Even loading the SP snap-in in PS generates the error.

Comment: Go to SQL instance for SharePoint and here

Comment: If you mean go to SQL Server to find that instance, I don't have access to that application. Sorry for the repeated questions.

Comment: So ask somebody who has this permissions. You cannot run scripts which you want if you havent proper permissions. Thats all.